# Example of proper use of SignerSignEx3

Tags: windows, winapi, cryptography, code-signing, authenticode

I was looking for any documentation of **SignerSignEx3**.

There are examples of how to use [SignerSignEx2](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1271890/EV-Code-Signing-with-a-hardware-token), however SignerSignEx3 has almost no documentation,. SignTool [uses it](https://twitter.com/vcsjones/status/861579952315133952) and in order to code sign properly and [time stamp the signed file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecCrypto/signertimestampex3), SignerSignEx3 should be used. Any example of how to use it?

Comment: I found this article https://vcsjones.com/2017/12/14/azure-signtool/

Comment: You linked to comprehensive documentation. What aspect do you feel is missing?

Comment: Formal one, like the one for SignerSignEx2(). Any idea why there isn't a Microsoft Docs entry for SignerSignEx2()?

Comment: What specific scenario are you facing, that `SignerSignEx2` does not address?

Comment: I would like to programmatically code sign Kernel drivers for Windows 10 using an EV certificate, including time stamping and root certificate. I thought I needed it for time stamping (SignerTimeStampEx3) but I was wrong. Its now only a matter of curiosity about formal documentation, and maybe the differences between SignerSignEx2() and SignerSignEx3()